# I want to separate numbers to 3 digits with commas in module in word application like this 1,000,000

Tags: vba, ms-word

the code shows me 100,000,0 instead of showing 1,000,000 how can I fix this.

```
Sub SeparateNumbers()
    Dim inputText As String
    Dim outputText As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim remainder As Integer
    
    
    ' Get the input text from the document
    inputText = Selection.Text
    
    ' Remove any non-numeric characters from the input text
    inputText = Replace(inputText, " ", "")
    
    ' Loop through the input text and separate numbers into groups of three digits
    remainder = Len(inputText) Mod 3
    If Len(inputText) = 7 Then
        outputText = "1,"
        inputText = Mid(inputText, 2)
        remainder = 2
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To Len(inputText)
        outputText = outputText & Mid(inputText, i, 1)
        If (Len(inputText) - i) Mod 3 = remainder And i < Len(inputText) Then
            outputText = outputText & ","
        End If
    Next i
    
    
          
    
    ' Display the output text in the document
    Selection.TypeText outputText
End Sub
```

Comment: ummmm guys I found the answer there is no need for help ;)

Comment: You could just delete the question then - right?

Comment: Welcome rubah! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You can also answer your own question an then 'accept' that answer. Next time you found an answer to your own question, delete or answer it

Answer (score 2):

use `Format()` function

```
Sub SeparateNumbers()
    Dim inputText As String
    
    
    ' Get the input text from the document
    inputText = Selection.Text
    

    
    ' Display the output text in the document
    Selection.TypeText Format(inputText, "0,000,000")
End Sub
```

a much more condensed version of which is the following:

```
Sub SeparateNumbers()
    With Selection
        .TypeText Format(.Text, "0,000,000")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the number from right to left instead of from left to right in order to focus on putting the comma 3 digits from the right in every situation:

```
Function FormatNumberGroups(inputText As String) As String
    Dim outputText As String = ""
    Dim reversedText As String = StrReverse(inputText)

    ' Declare i as an Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(reversedText)
        outputText = outputText & Mid(reversedText, i, 1)
        ' Add a comma after every group of three digits, but not at the end
        If i Mod 3 = 0 And i < Len(reversedText) Then
            outputText = outputText & ","
        End If
    Next i

    Return StrReverse(outputText)
End Function
```

This is how you call the function, including printing examples of the results:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim j As Long = 10
        While j <= 10000000000000
            ' Call the FormatNumberGroups function and print the result
            Console.WriteLine(j & " formatted is: " & FormatNumberGroups(CStr(j)))
            j *= 10 ' Multiply j by 10 in each iteration
        End While
    End Sub

    Function FormatNumberGroups(inputText As String) As String
    Dim outputText As String = ""
    Dim reversedText As String = StrReverse(inputText)

    ' Declare i as an Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(reversedText)
        outputText = outputText & Mid(reversedText, i, 1)
        ' Add a comma after every group of three digits, but not at the end
        If i Mod 3 = 0 And i < Len(reversedText) Then
            outputText = outputText & ","
        End If
    Next i

    Return StrReverse(outputText)
End Function

End Module
```